# Android phonegap connect to WCF service across domains

Tags: android, wcf, cordova

I have a phonegap 3.4 app written for android 4.4.2. My code for communication with WCF service works accross domains, as i have checked with my PC, and it also works in the emulator.  However, when I try to open my app on the phone, the data transfer never finishes- I neither get success nor error in my ajax call. Same thing happens if I open the html file in my phone's browser.

I had avast on my phone, but i turned it off, and I cant see what else might be interfering. So any help would be greatly appreciated. 
(Please keep in mind that my javascript-wcf communication works across domains, so I doubt that changes to my ajax or wcf are nescessary, at least I hope so.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, something went terribly wrong in my eclipse. Downloading pure eclipse and then installing adt plugin to it solved the issue.